# How to align the Chevron autoshape type

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The PowerPoint slide has one Chevron shape, when the user clicks on the shape and then run the macro it should add 7 Chevron shapes with different colors in the same slide distributed and aligned evenly and horizontally in the PowerPoint slide,however it is not getting aligned horizontally with the macros

I have tried adding the Chevron shapes and using incrementleft and align msolefts in macros tried to horizontally align with proper spacing in between, it didn't work properly.Kindly help me on the code.

> ### add the chevron shape

```
Sub testing
dim mychev as shape
dim shpind as integer
shpind = 2
for each mychev in activepresentation.slides(2).shapes
if shpind > 7 then
exit for 
end if
if mychev.name = "Chevron 1" then
with mychev.duplicate
.increment left 100
.increment top -10
mychev.name = "Chevron" & shpind
end iwth
shpind = shpind + 1
end if
next mychev
end sub
```

> ### also tried this way but failed

```
activepresentation.slides(2).shapes(i).select
selection.shaperange(i).align msolefts, false
```

> ### The expected result is like the below link image with each chevron having different colors.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwim_Kr4hYTjAhWy6nMBHSHSB8cQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.crystalgraphics.com%2Fpowerpoint%2Fslide.details.asp%3Fs%3DSLss3365-9&psig=AOvVaw1FqALPaVR84JPPdAZ1cWT4&ust=1561531937137917

Kindly help me on the code required for the same looks challenging since have not come across any work on these shapes.

Comment: Not overly familiar with VBA in PowerPoint but would something like `mychev.duplicate.Top = mychev.top` not work?  You could assign left by getting the `.Left` + `.Width` of the first shape then incrementing each time.

Comment: @Gareth I figured it out and thanks for your idea, I just used the same concept of `.increment left 100` and `.increment top -10` which helped me to adjust the space between the objects